# Use if() from c# .dll as if() in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, dll

I've been trying to figure out how use my c# dll with c# windows forms app and what I want to achieve is that inside my dll I'll create a if() condition and then use it in winforms.

Basically I want to create a function in the dll that will check if file exists and then in winforms use that as condition in button click example:

> if(mydll.Classname.Function == true)

my dll code

```
    public class Classname
{
    static void Function()
    {
        if (File.Exists("\\blabla\\something\\app.exe"))
        {

            

        }

    }
}
```

and then I linked the dll to the win forms and in win forms I tried this

```
        private void Launch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (mydll.Classname.Function == true)
        {


        }
```

}

when I try this it it underlines it and I can't build it.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid that your question is not at all clear. Do you have a static `bool` field or property in the class `Classname` in the namespace `mydll`?

Comment: Hmm I see, well I apologize but I don't actually know how should I format this since it's hard to explain. You mean like public static bool ?

Comment: Does `mydll.Classname.Function` actually refer to `PathNotFound.Function`? I'm a bit confused by the naming here...

Comment: ummm sorry Idk what do you mean?

Comment: Well, you've shown a method that doesn't return anything `Function`, defined in a class called `PathNotFound`. Separately to that, you've shown the following line of code: `if (mydll.Classname.Function == true)`. It's not clear how the two pieces of code you've shown relate to each other, if at all.

Comment: oops my bad, I edited it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET you create a DLL by creating a Class Library Project. You can then reference this project in your application. If this  Class Library Project is in the same Solution, you can add a Project Reference to your application (WinForms) pointing to this Library. If it is in another Solution, add an Assembly Reference to the DLL (usually the one residing in the bin/Release folder).

See also: [How to Add References to Your Visual Studio Project](https://www.webucator.com/article/how-to-add-references-to-your-visual-studio-projec/).

---

Now, to the design of your library function. This function must return a Boolean representing the result of the file test, that can be used in an if-statement in your application. Also, it must be public.

```cs
public static class FileFunctions
{
    public static bool AppExists()
    {
        return File.Exists(@"\blabla\something\app.exe");
    }
}
```

Note that I have also made the class static, so that it is not possible to create an object of this class, as it makes no sense here (`var makesNoSense = new FileFunctions();`).

Now, in your application, you can use this function:

```cs
private void Launch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileFunctions.AppExists())
    {

    }
}
```

You cannot reference the DLL directly in the code; however, If the class is in another namespace, you must reference this namespace. Either directly at the call site:

```
if (ClassLibraryNamespace.FileFunctions.AppExists())
```

... or by adding a `using` at the top of the code file, where there is probably already a `using System;`:

```cs
using ClassLibraryNamespace;
```

Note that I did not write `if (FileFunctions.AppExeExists() == true)`. The if-statement requires an expression yielding a Boolean, i.e., either `true` or `false`. This is what the function returns. It can be a comparison but this is not a requirement.